# command not doing anything when executing

Tags: bash, debug

***Sketch of situation***

I am running a small game server, openttd, on my (headless) raspberry pi 3B. I have been able to play this game, with a huge map, so resources are fine (if you don't mind waiting a bit).

Everytime I run a game, i do so with `openttd -D -f` to create a new game, and keep it running after i close my SSH connection. Everytime I close a game, i look up the games PID, kill the process, and if I want another game, i start a new one.

Since all that was going smoothly, i decided it was time to automate that repetitive cycle a bit.
I started out by filtering the PID of the first command that contained "openttd" out of the `ps aux` command, like this: `ps aux | grep "openttd" | tr -s " " | cut -s -d " " -f 2 | head -n 1`. Although not optimal, it works for me. When I tried to test it however, it didn't find any games. When I investigated this, i noticed the following:

***My specific problem***

Running the command `openttd -D -f` completes instantly, and with no output. (It should take some time to calculate stuff).

when running `openttd -D -f && tail -f ~/.openttd/openttd.cfg` nothing happens.
if i run `ps aux | grep openttd` I don't find any processes.

If i run the command `openttd -h` which should show (brief) help info, I get no output, and the command completes instantly.

The command is in my path, and is executable. I don't think I changed any config since it ran successfully. I am able to access the man page of the command, and it looks the same as usual.

***My generalized question***

How do you deal with a command that misbehaves as I described above?
What are things that should be checked?
What are possible causes for this situation?

Comment: What does `type openttd` or `which openttd`give?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille That made me realise my mistake! Thanks

Comment: You had your own openttd script?

Comment: Yes - rookie mistake...

Comment: No.  But I've learned to add the .sh extension to all my scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if openttd is what you think it is.  Execute

```
type openttd
```

or

```
which openttd
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Gerard H. Pille](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/80556/gerard-h-pille), who suggested to check the command path with `type openttd` or `which openttd`, I was able to track the source of my error: myself.

When I tried to automate the process of launching/stopping a game, I created a file called "openttd" in `/usr/local/bin`. The file was executable, but had no content, hence my error.

Renaming the file to something else fixed my issue.